# CSS grid responsive from a given max width and aspect ratio

Tags: css, css-grid

I've an issue with CSS Grid.
I define a grid

```
.cover {
  max-width: 1080;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}
```

And inside this grid I have some blocks

```
.horizontal {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
.large {
  grid-column: span 2;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.vertical {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 2;
}
.small {
  grid-column: span 1;
  grid-row: span 1;
}
```

Every block has an image inside, and I have only two variables: the max width of the grid, 1080px, and the aspect ratio of the small block, 360 x 280.
How to have this grid responsive keeping the aspect ratio of the blocks?

My html is easy

```
<div class="cover">
 <div class="horizontal"></div>
 <div class="small"></div>
 <div class="small"></div>
 <div class="horizontal"></div>
 <div class="small"></div>
 <div class="small"></div>
 <div class="small"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've read this [article](https://medium.com/compass-true-north/css-grid-maintaining-aspect-ratio-and-managing-overflow-ed54c510782a) and it helped me. Maybe _minmax()_ function for css grid layout helps too.

Comment: use `grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 360px);
  grid-auto-rows: 280px`? see https://jsfiddle.net/wtcpb9kz/